# Generate one API Gateway for multiple lambdas - in automated way

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I would like to build API Gateway in automated way (using some kind of framework), but I cannot find ideal solution.

The problem is that every framework is using one lambda (proxy) for entire API Gateway. I'm intrested in one API and multiple lambdas (with different persmissions and node_modules).

I was trying:
- claudiajs
- severless
- dawson

Do we have other options or I need to create it by myself via CloudFormation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask - what are you trying to achieve, whats the benefit in the functionality you're after?

Comment: I would like to split permissions per lambda eg. update only given tables or give acess to bucket in s3 + I would like to create zip files from local node_modules eg. lambda1 has ramda.js and lamda2 has other package. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

So all Lambda's on AWS have their own execution roles, regardless of framework. Under serverless ([serverless docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/)) you can specify a role for each Lambda by following the example in that link.

You can also individually package functions see [this](http://forum.serverless.com/t/is-this-expected-behavior-for-individually-packing-functions/330/4) forum thread for more info.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss it? Give me a sec I will create quick POC and eventually accept your answer. Many thanks!!!